# Definite Integration of Sec x dx within limit 0 to 1

Tags: calculus, integration

Examine the convergence of:

$$\int_0^1 \sec x dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}$  and $\cos x$ is nonzero on $[0,1]$, this means that $\sec$ is a bounded continuous function on $[0,1]$, so convergence is "automatic".

Comment: Thanks @5xum  But as per the book, this is divergant and the answer mentioned is Infinite.

Comment: @Deb The book is wrong.

Comment: @Deb if the integral is from 0 to 1 and you aren't multiplying $x$ by $\pi$ or $\pi/2$ or anything, then the integral is not divergent. Check the expression for your integral and the limits of integration.

Comment: @Deb Are you sure that the integral limits are $0$ to $1$? If they are, then the book is wrong. Also, if you already calculated the indefinite integral of the function, add it to your question (make an edit to your question).